# Function of $x$ which diverges for $x\to c$ while derivative converges to a constant

Tags: calculus, limits

Is there a function $f(x)$ of one real variable and a constant $c$ with the following two properties:

1. $\lim_{x\to c} f'(x)$ converges to some finite value
2. $\lim_{x\to c} f(x) = \infty$

With $\lim_{x\to\infty}$, I could take $f'(x) = \frac{x}{x+1}$. For the limes going to constant $c$, I tried a trival replacement using $f'(x) = \frac{1/(x-c)}{1/(x-c) + 1}$, but then end up with $f$ not being divergent.

Comment: Do you know the MVT ?

Comment: There might be a non-continuous function satisfying these requirements (although I'm not sure about even that), but as Bey showed in their answer, if the MVT is satisfied, there won't be such a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the [Mean Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) shows why no such function exists.

We can pick any two points $a,b \in \rm{Dom}(f)$ such that $a,b \neq c$ and calculate the secant slope $S(a,b):= \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$ formed by those two points $(a,f(a)), (b,f(b))$.

The Mean Value Theorem tells us $ \exists\delta \in (a,b): f'(\delta) = S(a,b)$.

However, since $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)= \infty$ then we can make $|S(a,b)|$ arbitrarily large by letting $b$ get arbitrarily close to $c$:

$$\forall a,b\neq c$$
$$\lim_{b \to c} |S(a,b)| = \infty$$

Therefore, $\lim_{x\to c} |f'(x)| =\infty$ since the sequence of derivatives are unbounded as you approach $c$.